# how to test if function was called (unit test angular)

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, mocking, jasmine

Hi I have an angular service.

```
...

return {
    setMixpanel: function(searchObject){
                  searchObject["referrer"] ? mixpanel.register({"$referrer":searchObject["referrer"]}) : mixpanel.register({"$referrer":""});

    }
}
```

In my unit test I probably have to `spyOn` `mixpanel` along with `register`. But I need to somehow mock mixpanel.register.

How do I mock `mixpanel.register` properly? Where does code go.

I mocked it as follows:

```
var mixpanel={
      register : function(object){
        return object
      }
    };
```

But where do I put this code? Is it correct?

I hope someone can help me out here?!

EDIT:
The test itself looks probably like this

```
it('should test', function(){
    spyOn(mixpanel,'register');
    redirectService.setMixpanel(search);
    expect(mixpanel.register).toHaveBeenCalledWith('...');
})
```

But in order to do that I need to mock mixpanel. If I just spyOn mixpanel, I will get an error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to create a spyObject first. There's no need to mock your service

```
beforeEach(function () {
    myServiceSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('myService');

    module(function ($provide) {
        $provide.value('myService', myServiceSpy);
    });
});
```

Test

```
describe("myService", function() {
   it("calls the getUser() function", function() {

      /* Maybe this line unnecessary, cant try it atm */
      spyOn(service, "getUser");
      expect(service.getUser).toHaveBeenCalled();
   });
});
```

If you want to test if `mixpanel.register` is called, you need to create a spy object of your mixpanel. With $provide you tell the test to use the spy instead of the real service.

```
describe('mixPanel', function () {
   mixPanelSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('mixPanel');

   beforeEach(module(function($provide) {
     $provide.value("mixpanel", mixPanelSpy);
   }));

   beforeEach(inject(function (_mixpanelService_) {
      mixpanelService = _mixpanelService_;
   }));

   it('should set mixpanel', function() {
       mixpanelService.setMixPanel('test');
       expect(mixpanel.register).toBeCalled();
   });
});
```

*wrote that out of my mind, maybe there're some clashes you need to fix*

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I know that I have to create a spy on it. Something like this. spyOn(mixpanel,'register');
    redirectService.setMixpanel(obejct);
    expect(mixpanel.register).toHaveBeenCalledWith('...'); But if I do not mock mixpanel.register first it will not be recognized

Comment: For more informations please share your test code by editing your question

Comment: thanks again. the problem is that mixpanel.register is not a function of my service but only a function that is called within my service function. In your code example, one should actually mock service.getuser right?

Comment: @user3383709 did you still need the to mock mixpanel ?